# how to create drop dwon time range using the time range in string form from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm saving the time range like this `09 : 00-12 : 31` or `15 : 00-17 : 00` in 24hr format. i explode this time like this:

```
                 $time = array();
                $time = explode('-',$data['tele_timings']);$starttime='';
                $starttime = $time[0];
                $endtime = $time[1];
```

the `$data['tele_timings']` is the time that i pick from the db . its format is i mentioned above. I have tried many methods but nothing is creating the drop down list of time range. one method i have tried is :

```
$time_start = $starttime;
            $time_end   = $endtime;

$timestamp_start = strtotime(date('d-m-Y').' '.$time_start);
$timestamp_end   = strtotime(date('d-m-Y').' '.$time_end);
$options_array = '';
while($timestamp_start <= $timestamp_end){
$options_array.='<option value="">'.date('H:i',    $timestamp_start).'</option>';

 $timestamp_start = $timestamp_start+900; //Adds 15 minutes     
 }
echo $options_array;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct.But you actual problem is that while you explode the string into start and end time for example, 09 : 00-12 : 31

star_time=09 : 00
end_time=12 : 31 stored.

This is not the intermediary result you required for proceeding in the right way.
So you need to remove all spaces in between them.For this purpose use str_replace() function..Accroding to your code use :

$starttime=str_replace(' ', '', $time[0]);
$endtime=str_replace(' ', '', $time[1]);
Then proceed with the same logic.
Wish you all the very best :)